# How can you generate real life terrain in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

## Goal

I am making a flight game on Roblox that requires real-world map data to generate terrain.

## Problems

I have absolutely no idea how to make this kind of program, and I have been unable to find any terrain generators that meet my requirements and have only found one terrain generator for Roblox.

## Requests

The terrain needs to be generated fast enough so that commercial planes, which travel at speeds of around 500 knots, will not fly out of generated terrain. Also, accurate airports need to be generated with taxiways and runways, as well as the airport building. In addition, I also need the taxiway and runway location data, as well as the location of taxiway markings so that planes can pathfind along taxiways and runways, as well as do an ILS approach. Finally, data that is used for terrain should be acquired live so that I don't have to create an enormous map and use up too much storage.

## THIS POST NO LONGER NEEDS ANSWERS

I have started working on a program to accomplish this. If finished, the project will be linked here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be high-quality terrain, but you can download map data from openstreetmap.org and create a mesh for the ground. Then use the building information to display buildings as basic shapes. Airports should also be easy to extract. I suggest creating one mesh per chunk, then stream the chunks required to the client, assuming that this works properly in Roblox. I'm not sure how detailed you want the meshes to be, but especially with two or more levels of detail, it should be no problem for the server.

Comment: The terrain doesn't need to be high quality and can be about the same quality as AirX 2020. Also, the file size for that kind of stuff would be massive if I were to do it for the entire world, even if it was at a smaller scale. I am looking for a system similar to AirX 2020. However, thanks for the idea!